# Synchronizing on collection inside map

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

Here is the sample code to illustrate the situation:

```
public class ConnectionRegistry {

    private ConcurrentMap<String, List<Connection>> registry = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public List<Connection> find(String key) {
        List<Connection> connections = registry.get(key);
        if (null == connections) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        synchronized(connections) {
            return new ArrayList(originalCopy);
        }
    }

    public void register(String key, Connection connection) {
        List<Connection> connections = registry.get(key);
        if (null == connections) {
            List<Connection> newConnections = new ArrayList<>();
            connections = registry.putIfAbsent(key, newConnections);
            if (null == connections) {
                connections = newConnections;
            }
        }
        synchronized(connections) {
            connections.add(connection);
        }
    }

}
```

In the above code I have a registry to manage connections indexed by key. I would like to make it thread safe, so I've used `ConcurrentMap` datastructure, in addition to the map, I want to make sure the `List` inside the map are also thread safe, thus I use the `synchronize` key word as shown in the above source code.

However my IDE warns me that it is a ***synchronization on local variable*** and ***it is very difficult to guarantee correctness when such synchronization is used***.

Is there any other way or good practice to handle this situation?

Comment: What a bout using a `Vector` instead of `List`

Comment: You could also do a wrapper for List. Just override some List methods (or even implement the List interface) and call super() everywhere. Also, provide an `Object getLockableObject()` object inside each wrapper list. This way, you can synchronize on it from outside.

Comment: Alternatively, you could call `Collections.synchronizedList()`, which pretty much does what I suggested above. Have a look at `Collections.SynchronizedList` class to see what's what.

Comment: All sound correct solutions to me. Thumb up for Vector one, very neat!

Comment: @Yahya can you put it as an answer so that I can grant you the credential?

Comment: @Cargeh please add your answer also, I can vote up for it

Comment: @green Cheers man , but it's just about changing some words in your code... I think they will downvote me :(

Comment: not at all. I will accept your answer and up vote it

Comment: @green voting up the comments would be appreciated and beyond enough :) Thanks for being a good sport though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector implements a dynamic array. It is similar to ArrayList, but with two differences:

- Vector is synchronized.
- Vector contains many legacy methods that are not part of the collections framework.

And From The Documentation:

> Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is **synchronized**. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.

With a few changes the code would be:

```
public class ConnectionRegistry {

    private ConcurrentMap<String, List<Connection>> registry = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public List<Connection> find(String key) {
        List<Connection> connections = registry.get(key);
        if (null == connections) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        return new Vector<Connection>(originalCopy);

    }

    public void register(String key, Connection connection) {
        List<Connection> connections = registry.get(key);
        if (null == connections) {
            List<Connection> newConnections = new Vector<Connection>();
            connections = registry.putIfAbsent(key, newConnections);
            if (null == connections) {
                connections = newConnections;
            }
        }

        connections.add(connection);

 }
```

Comment: Actually I prefer to leave the interface (return type) as `List`, but use `Vector` as internal implementation

Comment: Don't ever use `Vector`. It's been obsolete for nineteen years. That's a long time. How long have you been programming in Java?

Comment: There is even no `@Deprecated` mark on `Vector` how come it is **obsolete**. Yes it is known that `ArrayList` should be used to replace `Vector` (in most cases), but for this specific case, I don't think `Vector` is a bad choice. BTW challenging people's industry experience doesn't help to make your opinion more solid

Comment: Even I mentioned in my answer that the ArrayList is recommended over the Vector, though he downvoted it! Is he more knowledgeable than Oracle itself!

Answer (score 1):

Just like ConcurrentHashMap, you can synchronize the ArrayList using [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). CopyOnWriteArrayList provides same thread safety but for an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a synchronized list you can get by calling Collections.synchronizedList() or use vector as mentioned in above answer.Vector and synchronized ArrayList are much slower than their concurrent counterparts CopyOnWriteArrayList because locks the whole collection e.g. whole List so even it does not allow multiple read so you can consider concurrent collection never locks the whole Map or List.

They achieve thread safety by using  techniques like lock stripping or in CopyOnWriteArrayList allows multiple reader threads to read without synchronization and when a write happens it copies the whole ArrayList and swap with a newer one.

-CopyOnWriteArrayList will likely to outperform synchronized ArrayList if ArrayList is mostly used for read only purpose but if its mix of read and write then  Collections.synchronizedList() one is also good. One more difference is How it iterate.

-The Iterator returned from synchronized ArrayList is a fail fast but iterator returned by CopyOnWriteArrayList is a fail-safe iterator.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. From the API document it says "This is ordinarily too costly, but may be more efficient than alternatives when traversal operations vastly outnumber mutations". However it might not fit into my usage scenario, say keeping track of websocket connections and we know connections could close and new connection can arrive frequently